# How to enable azure vm application insights monitoring agent using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

i'm getting the following error:

> Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure
> when processing extension 'vm-insights-monitorAgent-vmazpcuwldship3'.
> Error message: "Failed to enable application monitoring for IIS:
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find applicationHost.config at
> C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config\r\nFile
> name:
> 'C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config'\r\n
> at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Redfield.Configurator.RuntimeConfigurators.IISConfigurator.UpdateApplicationHostConfig(IAppInsightsConfiguratorLogger
> logger, Boolean enable, Boolean skipMissingApplicationHostConfig,
> ISystem system)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Redfield.Configurator.RuntimeConfigurators.IISConfigurator.Enable(IRuntimePaths
> runtimePaths, IAppInsightsConfiguratorLogger logger, Boolean
> writeToApplicationHostConfig, Boolean
> skipMissingApplicationHostConfig, ISystem system)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Redfield.Configurator.RedfieldConfigurator.Enable(IRuntimePaths
> runtimePaths, IAppInsightsConfiguratorLogger logger,
> RedfieldConfiguration redfieldConfiguration, Boolean
> enableInstrumentationEngine, Boolean writeToApplicationHostConfig,
> Boolean skipMissingApplicationHostConfig)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.VmExtensionHandler.VmExtensionHandler.Enable(HandlerEnvironment
> handlerEnvironment, String configSequenceNumber)"\r\n\r\n "

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm_insight_monitor_agent" {
  name                  = "vm-insights-monitorAgent-${var.vm_name}"
  virtual_machine_id    = var.vm_id
  publisher             = "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics"
  type                  = "ApplicationMonitoringWindows"
  type_handler_version  = "2.8"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
 
  settings = <<SETTINGS
        {
          "redfieldConfiguration": {
            "instrumentationKeyMap": {
              "filters": [
                {
                  "appFilter": ".*",
                  "machineFilter": ".*",
                  "virtualPathFilter": ".*",
                  "instrumentationSettings" : {
                    "connectionString": "InstrumentationKey=${var.appi_conn_string}"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
SETTINGS
 
  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
        {}
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use an inappropriate VM extension. You can follow the examples [here](https://diverse.services/building-azure-monitor-for-application-monitoring-with-terraform/). It shows the examples both for the monitor agent and the monitor dependency agent.

Comment: Thanks for your info, but i need it in terraform as i mentioned above code.

Comment: @BasavarajBiradar Do you have applications already running on IIS inside the VM? It seems the insight need the applicationHost.config to monitor the application.

Comment: no, i'm creating the new VM using terraform and  configuring the vm_insight_monitor_agent. It's new VM no applications running

Comment: @BasavarajBiradar It seems that's the problem. You can see [here](https://cloud-right.com/2019/12/azure-appinsights), the extension you want to install is used to monitor the application running inside the VM. So maybe you must run the application before installing the extension. And make sure this extension is the right one you want.

Comment: @BasavarajBiradar Any updates on this question? Do you still work on it?

Comment: I'm looking for bypassing the **applicationHost.config** , because when we set up new VM at the same time i need to configure the application insights agent. we'll not wait for till the application deployment happens on new created vm.

Comment: @BasavarajBiradar If you need to configure all the things at the creation time, the VM extension is not suitable. You can use the cloud-init to install the agent via the script, shell for Linux, and PowerShell for Windows.

Comment: i'm looking into CustomScript which is installed through vm_extension

Comment: @BasavarajBiradar VM extension is executed when the VM has configured. And what about this question? Do you still work on it?