# Terraform enable VM Insights

Tags: azure, logging, azure-devops, terraform, azure-application-insights

Did someone managed to enable via terraforms Insights for a VM?

i'm able to create a VM, enable logging, but not enable insights..

i've seen this question: but don't find a clear answer..
[How to enable azure vm application insights monitoring agent using terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65428101/how-to-enable-azure-vm-application-insights-monitoring-agent-using-terraform)

Here is my full terraform script that i'm using for tests, i'm running it directly on the cloud shell from azure.

```
    # Configure the Azure provider
provider "azurerm" {
    # The "feature" block is required for AzureRM provider 2.x.
    features {}
}
variable "prefix" {
  default = "tfvmex"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "main" {
  name                     = "omstesttest22"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location                 = "westus"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "law02" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-logAnalytics"
 location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
 sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}



resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "example" {
  solution_name         = "ContainerInsights"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law02.id
  workspace_name        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law02.name

  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/ContainerInsights"
  }
}

#===================================================================
# Set Monitoring and Log Analytics Workspace
#===================================================================
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "oms_mma02" {
  name                       = "test-OMSExtension"
virtual_machine_id         =  azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                       = "OmsAgentForLinux"
  type_handler_version       = "1.12"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceId" : "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law02.workspace_id}"
    }
  SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceKey" : "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law02.primary_shared_key}"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

Hope it was clear.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you face some errors? if so, could you please provide the error message?

Comment: Is there a typo `"workspaceId" : "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law02.workspace_id}",`? There is an extra comma?

Comment: ups.. to upload the code i changed the name of the azurerm_storage_account and add an invalid name.. already updated id.

Comment: @NancyXiong also true... my bad, deleted some of my tries to add insights and that comma got lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-enable-overview#agents), VM insights require the following two agents to be installed on each virtual machine to be monitored.

- **Log Analytics agent**. Collects events and performance data from the virtual machine or virtual machine scale set and delivers it to the Log Analytics workspace. Deployment methods for the Log Analytics agent on Azure resources use the VM extension for Windows and Linux.
- **Dependency agent**. Collects discovered data about processes running on the virtual machine and external process dependencies, which are used by the Map feature in VM insights. The Dependency agent relies on the Log Analytics agent to deliver its data to Azure Monitor. Deployment methods for the Dependency agent on Azure resources use the VM extension for Windows and Linux.

After my validation, you can add the DependencyAgent extension to your existing code.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "da" {
  name                       = "DAExtension"
  virtual_machine_id         =  azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent"
  type                       = "DependencyAgentLinux"
  type_handler_version       = "9.5"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

}
```

[image]

For more information, read [Configure Log Analytics workspace for VM insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-configure-workspace?tabs=CLI#create-log-analytics-workspace) and [Enable VM insights guest health (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-health-enable?tabs=powershell)

Comment: I will test this. i'll give some feedback asap

Comment: that was exactly what was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

please use the product "OMSGallery/VMInsights" (instead of "OMSGallery/ContainerInsights")

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "..." {
  solution_name         = "..."
  location              = ...
  resource_group_name   = ...
  workspace_resource_id = ...
  workspace_name        = ...

  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/VMInsights"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**To deploy it using Terraform:**

Deploy a log analytics workspace and a VMInsights solution associated with the workspace.

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "law" {
  name                      = "LogAnalyticsWorkspace"
  location                  = "Your location"
  resource_group_name       = "Your resource group"
  sku                       = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days         = "your retention in days"
  internet_ingestion_enabled= true
  internet_query_enabled    = false
  tags                      = "Your tags"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "vminsights" {
  solution_name         = "VMInsights"
  location              = "Your location"
  resource_group_name   = "Your resource group"
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.id
  workspace_name        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.name
  tags                  = "Your tags"

  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/VMInsights"
  }
}
```

Deploy VM with as usual with OMSAgent and DependencyAgentWindows extensions:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm" {
   ......
   ......
}
```

OMS for Windows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-windows

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "omsext" {
  name                  = "OMSExtension" 
  virtual_machine_id    = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher             = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                  = "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent"
  type_handler_version  = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "workspaceId": "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.id}"
    }
  SETTINGS
  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceKey": "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.primary_shared_key}"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS  

  tags                       = "Your tags"
}
```

DA Agent for Windows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-dependency-windows

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "DAAgent" {
  name                       = "DAAgentExtension"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent"
  type                       = "DependencyAgentWindows"
  type_handler_version       = "9.10"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  tags                       = "Your tags"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft have changed the settings needed in the MicrosoftMonitoringAgent extensions, and the terraform specified by @Bill no longer works as of June 2022. The Terraform that worked for me was:

```
# Import the subscription and resource groups
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "rg-name"
  provider = azurerm
}

resource "random_password" "windowsvm-password" {
  length           = 24
  special          = false
}

# Define the VM itself
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "windowsvm-c" {
  name                            = "mywindowsvm"
  computer_name                   = "mywindowsvm"
  resource_group_name             = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                        = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  size                            = "Standard_B2s"
  admin_username                  = "adminlogin"
  admin_password                  = random_password.windowsvm-password.result
  identity { type = "SystemAssigned" }

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.windowsvm-c-nic.id,
  ]
  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  patch_mode          = "AutomaticByPlatform"
  hotpatching_enabled = true
}


# Add logging and monitoring
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "law" {
  name                      = "vmloganalytics"
  resource_group_name       = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg-c.name
  location                  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg-c.location
  sku                       = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days         = 365
  internet_ingestion_enabled= true
  internet_query_enabled    = false
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "vminsights" {
  solution_name         = "vminsights"
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg-c.name
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg-c.location
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.id
  workspace_name        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.name
  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/VMInsights"
  }
}

# This extension is needed for other extensions
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "daa-agent" {
  name                       = "DependencyAgentWindows"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windowsvm-c.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent"
  type                       = "DependencyAgentWindows"
  type_handler_version       = "9.10"
  automatic_upgrade_enabled  = true
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
}


# Add logging and monitoring extensions
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "monitor-agent" {
  depends_on = [  azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.daa-agent  ]
  name                  = "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent"
  virtual_machine_id    = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windowsvm-c.id
  publisher             = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor"
  type                  = "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent"
  type_handler_version  =  "1.5"
  automatic_upgrade_enabled  = true
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "msmonitor-agent" {
  depends_on = [  azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.daa-agent  ]
  name                  = "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent"  # Must be called this
  virtual_machine_id    = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windowsvm-c.id
  publisher             = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                  = "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent"
  type_handler_version  =  "1.0"
  # Not yet supported
  # automatic_upgrade_enabled  = true
  # auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "workspaceId": "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.id}",
        "azureResourceId": "${azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windowsvm-c.id}",
        "stopOnMultipleConnections": "false"
    }
  SETTINGS
  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceKey": "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.primary_shared_key}"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

Note the extended settings under "msmonitor-agent"

Comment: I enabled `DependencyAgentWindows`, but VM insights still doesn't shows up on Portal. May I know if the another extension `MicrosoftMonitoringAgent` is must this to work? Isn't this to be deprecate by `AzureMonitorAgent`?

Answer (score 1):

Here are few articles for this topic, maybe you can reference to:

- [**Azure Monitor for application monitoring with Terraform**](https://diverse.services/building-azure-monitor-for-application-monitoring-with-terraform/)
- [**Azure Insights: Terraform; Log Analytics Workspaces; Custom scripts with Arc-enabled servers; Virtual WAN resources**](https://msdynamicsworld.com/story/azure-insights-terraform-log-analytics-workspaces-custom-scripts-arc-enabled-servers-virtual)

Answer (score 0):

In my case to enable VM Insight and AMA, the approach was mix of Azure `Policy` and `terraform`:

- An Azure `Policy` that

  - Finds all the Microsoft Windows VMs in scope and enables `AzureMonitorWindowsAgent` via Remediation task. Ref: [[1]](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/building-a-policy-to-deploy-the-new-azure-monitor-agent/ba-p/2234423) & [[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-manage?tabs=azure-portal#built-in-policy-initiatives)
- Terraform snippet to:

  - Create `Data collection Rule` existing in management subscription

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "avd_dcr" {
    for_each      = { for dcrule in var.data_collection_rules : dcrule.name => dcrule }
  name                = "fer-avd-dcr-${each.value.name}"
  resource_group_name = "${each.value.resource_group_name}"
  location            = "${each.value.location}"
  description         = "data collection rule for AVD Hostpools"

  data_sources {
    performance_counter {
      name                          = "perfCounterDataSource60"
      streams                       = ["Microsoft-Perf"]
      sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 60
      counter_specifiers = [
        "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% Processor Time",
         # ...
      ]
    }

    performance_counter {
      name                          = "VMInsightsPerfCounters"
      streams                       = ["Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"]
      sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 60
      counter_specifiers = [
        "\\VmInsights\\DetailedMetrics"
      ]
    }

  }

  destinations {
    log_analytics {
      workspace_resource_id = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.avd_law_ws.id
      name = "la-${each.value.name}"
    }
  } 

  data_flow {
    streams       = ["Microsoft-Perf", "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"]
    destinations  = ["la-${each.value.name}"]
  } 

  stream_declaration {
    stream_name = "Custom-MyTable_CL"
    column {
      name = "TimeGenerated"
      type = "datetime"
    }
    column {
      name = "RawData"
      type = "string"
    }
  }

  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

Note:

- Policy remediation requires a managed identity with appropriate RBACs.
- For VMInsights to show up on portal, DCR Requires the `performance_counter` both streams `Microsoft-Perf` and `Microsoft-InsightsMetrics`