# Enable Azure Monitor for existing Virtual machines using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file, terraform-provider-openstack

I am trying to enable azure monitor feature for existing virtual machines which checks for health and performance of the VM using terraform but I am not able to find the right documentation for the same. Can you help me for the same because I want detailed monitoring for azure?

Comment: this might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633650/terraform-enable-vm-insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For enabling VMinsights on Existing Vm’s you need to have the data source for the VM and then deploy Storage account,log analytics workspace ,log analytics solution,log analytics agent for OS of the VM and a depending agent for the OS of the VM.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "test1"
  resource_group_name = "testgroup"# where your VM resides in your subscription
}

output "virtual_machine_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "main" {
  name                     = "vminsightstest1234"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.resource_group_name # where your VM resides in your subscription
  location                 = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.location # which region your VM resides 
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "LAW" {
  name                = "vminsights-logAnalytics"
 location            = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.location #which region your VM resides 
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.resource_group_name # where your VM resides in your subscription
 sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "example" {
  solution_name         = "ContainerInsights"
  location              = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.location # which region your VM resides 
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.resource_group_name # where your VM resides in your subscription
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.LAW.id
  workspace_name        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.LAW.name
  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/ContainerInsights"
  }
}
# Agent for Linux
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "OMS" {
  name                       = "test-OMSExtension"
  virtual_machine_id         =  data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                       = "OmsAgentForLinux"
  type_handler_version       = "1.13"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceId" : "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.LAW.workspace_id}"
    }
  SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceKey" : "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.LAW.primary_shared_key}"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}

# Dependency Agent for Linux
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "da" {
  name                       = "DAExtension"
  virtual_machine_id         =  data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent"
  type                       = "DependencyAgentLinux"
  type_handler_version       = "9.5"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

}
#Agent for Windows
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "MMA" {
  name                       = "test-MMAextension"
  virtual_machine_id         =  data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                       = "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceId" : "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.LAW.workspace_id}"
    }
  SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "workspaceKey" : "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.LAW.primary_shared_key}"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}

# Dependency Agent for Windows
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "da" {
  name                       = "DAExtension"
  virtual_machine_id         =  data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent"
  type                       = "DependencyAgentWindows"
  type_handler_version       = "9.5"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

}
```

**Note:** Add Monitoring Agent and dependency agent as per your OS requirement.

The above code I have tested in my lab for a Windows VM that I had created.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I followed the instructions and noticed that azure is recognizing the solution as a 'legacy' type, see https://imgur.com/a/me1vB5a,  is it possible to configure with terraform using the new Azure monitor way?