# Use terraform to add a VM to the new Azure Monitoring (without OMS Agent)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-monitoring

When I configure Azure Monitoring using the OMS solution for VMs with this answer [Enable Azure Monitor for existing Virtual machines using terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389589/enable-azure-monitor-for-existing-virtual-machines-using-terraform), I notice that this feature is being deprecated and Azure prefers you move to the new monitoring solution (Not using the log analytics agent).

Azure allows me to configure VM monitoring using this GUI, but I would like to do it using terraform.

[image]

Is there a particular setup I have to use in terraform to achieve this? (I am using a Linux VM btw)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The omsagent has been marked as legacy and Azure now has a new monitoring agent called "Azure Monitor agent" . The solution given below is for Linux, Please check the Official Terraform docs for Windows machines.

We need three things to do the equal UI counterpart in Terraform.

- azurerm_log_analytics_workspace
- azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule
- azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule_association

Below is the example code:

```
    data "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
      name                = var.vm_name
      resource_group_name = var.az_resource_group_name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspace" {
      name                = "${var.project}-${var.env}-log-analytics"
      location            = var.az_location
      resource_group_name = var.az_resource_group_name
      sku                 = "PerGB2018"
      retention_in_days   = 30
    }
    
     resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent" {        
      name                       = "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent"
      publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor"
      type                       = "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent"
      type_handler_version       = "1.0"
      auto_upgrade_minor_version = "true"
    
      virtual_machine_id = data.azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
    }
    
    
     resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "example" {
      name                = "example-rules"
      resource_group_name = var.az_resource_group_name
      location            = var.az_location
    
      destinations {
        log_analytics {
          workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspace.id
          name                  = "test-destination-log"
        }
    
        azure_monitor_metrics {
          name = "test-destination-metrics"
        }
      } 
    
      data_flow {
        streams      = ["Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"]
        destinations = ["test-destination-log"]
      }
    
      data_sources {
    
        performance_counter {
          streams                       = ["Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"]
          sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 60
          counter_specifiers            = ["\\VmInsights\\DetailedMetrics"]
          name                          = "VMInsightsPerfCounters"
        }
    }
     }
    
    # associate to a Data Collection Rule
    resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule_association" "example1" {
      name                    = "example1-dcra"
      target_resource_id      = data.azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
      data_collection_rule_id = azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule.example.id
      description             = "example"
    }
```

Reference:

[monitor_data_collection_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_data_collection_rule)

[monitor_data_collection_rule_association](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_data_collection_rule_association)

Comment: Is this working okay in June 2023? I've been trying to get my Linux VMs connected but my Log Analytics workspace is reporting "0 Linux computers connected via Azure Monitor Linux agent" despite my data collection rule showing my VMs?

Comment: Update - ensure you have an identity block defined for the VM, if you use SystemAssigned then no other changes to the above answer are needed. More info - https://medium.com/@t.costantini89/send-linux-vm-logs-to-an-azure-log-analytics-workspace-using-terraform-and-the-azure-monitor-agent-939d481cc48a